# Writing a list of NumPy arrays to csv

Tags: python, arrays, csv, numpy

I have a getX() which gives a 2D array(shape=(18,2)) as an output for each frame of an image. I want to add this continuously updating array to the csv. I have used the following code. But it is giving me only one row(probably for only one frame).

```
[array([178.,  76.]), array([184.,  92.]), array([164.,  90.]), array([154., 116.]), array([160., 126.]), array([204.,  94.]), array([208., 124.]), array([190., 132.]), array([164., 152.])]
```

I have tried this:

```
with open("data.csv",mode ='w') as csvfile:
        wr = csv.writer(csvfile, quoting = csv.QUOTE_ALL,dialect="excel")
        get_val = oneObject.getX(currentFrameIndex)
        for  humanPos in get_val:
            wr.writerow(humanPos)
```

Comment: are those list of numpy array?

Comment: yes. it is a nD array

Comment: In case it isn't clear from the answers, `np.savetxt` is designed to write a 2d array.  Internally it is quite simple.  It makes input an array if it isn't already, and then just iterates over the rows, doing a python formatted write of the `tuple(row)`.  So if your list makes a nice 2d numeric array it should work fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can un-nest `data` with `itertools.chain.from_iterable` and use `wr.writerow`.

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> 
>>> with open("data.csv", mode='w') as csvfile:
...:      wr = csv.writer(csvfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL, dialect="excel")
...:      wr.writerow(chain.from_iterable(data))
```

Output:

```
$ cat data.csv
"178.0","76.0","184.0","92.0","164.0","90.0","154.0","116.0","160.0","126.0","204.0","94.0","208.0","124.0","190.0","132.0","164.0","152.0"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can save the numpy array's directly to csv, you don't need any other module.

```
import numpy as np
array = np.asarray([ [1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9] ])
numpy.savetxt("output.csv", array, delimiter=",")
```

To save it in single row and quote the output, you can use the `ravel` like @jpp suggested.

```
import numpy as np
array = np.asarray([ [1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9] ])
np.savetxt('output.csv', np.array(array).ravel()[None], fmt='"%s"', delimiter=',')
```

Comment: @timgeb that can be done, I will update the code shortly

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`np.ndarray.ravel`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html) after converting your list of arrays (`data`) to a single array. Then use either the `csv` module or NumPy, depending on the precise output you require.

#### `csv`

```
with open('data.csv', mode='w') as csvfile:
    wr = csv.writer(csvfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL, dialect='excel')
    wr.writerow(np.array(data).ravel())
```

Output:

```
"178.0","76.0","184.0","92.0","164.0","90.0","154.0","116.0","160.0","126.0","204.0","94.0","208.0","124.0","190.0","132.0","164.0","152.0"
```

---

#### `numpy`

To save on one line you need to slice via `[None]`. In addition, you can specify formatting via the `fmt` parameter of [`np.savetxt`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html). If you require text-based storage, this solution should be preferred to save and read arrays via NumPy.

```
np.savetxt('data.csv', np.array(data).ravel()[None], fmt='%d', delimiter=',')
```

Output:

```
178,76,184,92,164,90,154,116,160,126,204,94,208,124,190,132,164,152
```